# (Connexion 3.0.2) ModuleNotFoundError: Please install connexion using the 'flask' extra

Tags: python, flask, pip, connexion

#### Problem

I use connextion with Flask. Today I upgraded connexion from 2.14.2 to 3.0.2 and see `ModuleNotFoundError: Please install connexion using the 'flask' extra`.

https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

I checked the official documentation, which says "To leverage the FlaskApp, make sure you install connexion using the flask extra."

#### Question

How can I install connexion using the flask extra?
The documentation says the command is `pip install connexion[<extra>]`, but I see an error message "no matches found: connexion[flask]".

```
% pip install connexion[flask]
zsh: no matches found: connexion[flask]
```

#### Environment

- Python 3.12.0
- Flask 3.0.0
- Connexion 3.0.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+no+matches+found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/issues/779#issuecomment-441081238

I find this error was caused by `zsh`. `pip install "connexion[flask]"` worked. (Double quotations are needed.)